# DateForm Python-Flask - [u'Not a valid date value']}

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm developing a WEB APP and at some point I want to create a new entry to my Politic table. I could do it until I had to add some dates. The form isnt accepting the input due to a wrong date format. Lets look into it..

I have this form:

```
class PoliticForm(FlaskForm):
  publicName = StringField('Public Name', validators=[DataRequired("Please enter politician public name.")])
  completeName = StringField('Complete Name', validators=[DataRequired("Please enter politician complete name.")])
  startDate = DateField('Start Date', format='%m-%d-%Y', validators=[DataRequired("Please enter the politician start Date.")])
  endDate = DateField('End Date', format='%m-%d-%Y', validators=(validators.Optional(),))
  submit = SubmitField('Add Politician', validators=(validators.Optional(),))
```

but somehow the datefield isnt right because my form can't validate the **startDate** field nor the **endDate** field. 
This is my create function:

```
@app.route("/create_politician", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def create_politician():
  form = PoliticForm()

  if request.method == "POST":
    print form.validate()
    flash(form.errors)
    if form.validate() == False:
      return render_template('createPolitician.html', form=form)
    else:
      print form.startDate.data
      newpolitician = Politic(form.publicName.data, form.completeName.data, form.startDate.data, form.endDate.data)
      print form.startDate.data
      db.session.add(newpolitician)
      db.session.commit()
      return redirect(url_for('home'))

  elif request.method == "GET":
    return render_template("createPolitician.html", form=form)
```

and on that        **flash(form.errors)**
I get the following:

> {'startDate': ['Please enter the politician start Date.'], 'endDate': [u'Not a valid date value']}

**models.py**

```
class Politic(db.Model):
  __searchable__ = ['publicName', 'completeName']
  __tablename__ = 'politics'

  idPolitician = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  publicName = db.Column(db.String(150))
  completeName = db.Column(db.String(300))
  startDate = db.Column(db.Date)
  endDate = db.Column(db.Date)

  def __init__(self, publicName, completeName, startDate, endDate):
    self.publicName = publicName.title()
    self.completeName = completeName.title()
```

**.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="/create_politician">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

        <div class="form-group">
          {{ form.publicName.label }}
          {{ form.publicName }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          {{ form.completeName.label }}
          {{ form.completeName }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          {{ form.startDate.label }}
          {{ form.startDate }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          {{ form.endDate.label }}
          {{ form.endDate }}
        </div>

        {{ form.submit(class="btn-primary") }}

      </form>
```

Any idea, what is wrong. Is there any way to format the date input in order to match what the form is asking for?

Thank you

Regards

Answer (score 1):

actually, the form will validate with that format %Y-%m-%d, and in your field definition format='%m-%d-%Y' does not works for me for some reason, so try to:
 - remove format='%m-%d-%Y' in the datefield definition so keep in flask default format
 -try to print the date formt received on your view, and format it to %Y-%m-%d

hope this helps